# Exception Handling Error

Tags: java, exception

When a method throws an exception, it searches through the call stack to find a handler right? In that sense, why is there an error with **exep.second();**? even though i've caught the exception in method **second()**. Here's my code:

```
public class Exep {
void first()throws IOException{
    throw new IOException("device error");
}
void second()throws IOException{
    try{
        first();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    Exep exep = new Exep();
    exep.second();
}
```

}

But the error disappears on adding  **throws IOException** to the **main()**. Why?

Comment: Can you show us the expected output and actual output?

Comment: `IOException` is a checked exception. The compiler doesn't know that your call to `exep.second()` won't throw one, so your code doesn't compile.

Comment: @byrox I was learning Exception handling and i just wanted to print "device error" when the exception is caught.

Comment: @jsheeran or because i threw the exception from second()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IOException is a checked exception, and so must be handled in some way.  Adding `throws IOException` to main suppresses this behavior, but it is not good practice.

In `second()`, you catch all exceptions from `first()`, but you still include the `throws IOException` in the declaration of `second()`.  This is not necessary, because you can guarantee that any exception thrown by `first()` will be caught and handled in `second()`.

For more reading: [Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Answer (score 1):

If you declare `void second() throws IOException` and then you call the method in main, you need to catch the exception this method may throw, just like you did with the `first()` method. In that case you simply don't need the `throws` clause in `second()`.

Answer (score 1):

You explicitly declared that method `second()` throws an exception. Compiler is unaware that exception is actually being caught within a method. Move the `catch` part into `main()` and the error will disappear. Or even better, remove the `throws` statement since you are not throwing anything.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling the compiler that `second()` throws IOException, but when you call `second()` you aren't wrapping it in a try/catch block. If you want to leave it as is then you need to include a try catch block inside your main.

However, as you have it, you're never throwing an exception from inside of `second()` so you can remove the line `throws IOException` from there.